# USB key - folder parameters - changing access rights

Tags: 14.04, usb, windows, filesystem, usb-drive

There is an MS Windows computer in my lab, which is sadly infected by some strange trojans and viruses. One USB key got into trouble while it was plugged on to the computer. Scanning with an antivirus (McAfee) removed all the viruses.

I put this particular USB key into my linux machine and I was able to see all the folders. However, on a Windows machine, these folders and files were not visible.

By issuing `attrib -h -s *` I was able to make some of the files visible. However, the folders won't still be visible.

Is there any Linux command with which I could make these folders visible again on the Windows machine?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just examine the folders in Linux?

Also, I'd be certain to scan the Windows machine that you plugged the USB key into.

Comment: The person, to whom the USB key belongs to, is not a Linux guy.